# InputStream is null when i try to download gpx file from server and parse it

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, gpx

The problem is that downloading gpx file through http get request (retrofit) on Android device, parse it and show the route on google maps.

I have done first thing using retrofit and saved the file like "cyclingRoute.gpx" to downloads file on device like this:

```
NetworkBuilder.getAppNetwork().getRoute(routeId).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

        Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@", "API SUCCESS");
        try {
            File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            File file = new File(path, "cyclingRoute.gpx");
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            IOUtils.write(response.body().bytes(), fileOutputStream);
            parseRoute(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@", "API FAILS" + t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

for the parsing part i used a third party library from android arsenal: https://github.com/ticofab/android-gpx-parser

```
GPXParser mParser = new GPXParser();
Gpx parsedGpx = null;
try {
    InputStream  is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(file.getName());
    parsedGpx = mParser.parse(is);
} catch (IOException | XmlPullParserException e) {
    // do something with this exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (parsedGpx == null) {
    // error parsing track
} else {
    // do something with the parsed track
    List<Track> tracks = parsedGpx.getTracks();
    for (int i = 0; i < tracks.size(); i++) {
        Track track = tracks.get(i);
        Log.d(TAG, "track " + i + ":");
        List<TrackSegment> segments = track.getTrackSegments();
        for (int j = 0; j < segments.size(); j++) {
            TrackSegment segment = segments.get(j);
            Log.d(TAG, "  segment " + j + ":");
            for (TrackPoint trackPoint : segment.getTrackPoints()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "    point: lat " + trackPoint.getLatitude() + ", lon " + trackPoint.getLongitude());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i run the code "InputStream is" being null and throws an exception. Where am i doing wrong?

Instead of this line -> InputStream  is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(file.getName());

i tried this one as well -> InputStream in = getAssets().open("cycylingRoute.gpx");

and that throws an exception telling that no directory or file is found.

and also I am planing to collect all the tracks in json and pass it to google maps (if it is a correct way to do it). Any suggestions on that?

I would really appriciate if you help meee!!

Thanks.

Comment: Questions that are short and concise usually get better and quicker answers. From personal experience I'd suggest you try to make the question easier to read. 
If you really need to elaborate, break up the question to a short version at the top that will be followed by the elaboration section. This really helped to write better questions: [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: The class loader would not be looking in the external storage directory for the file name.  Have you tried just using the File approach just as you did in writing the file?

Answer (score 0):

In `InputStream in = getAssets().open("cycylingRoute.gpx");` where do you define "Downloads"?

You are using `File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);` to store a file.